# How to add translations to my custom validation

Tags: magento2, javascript, localisation, validation

I have added my own custom validations, with a JS mixin, like:

```
validator.addRule(
    'validate-jurgis',
    function (value) {
        if (value.match(/\d/)) {return false;}
        else {return true;}
    },
    $.mage.__('Address should contain a house number')
);
```

How do I add translations to the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add translations in module's i18n folder, theme folder or language pack inside your language csv file. Magento will "see" that you're using the translation inside a javascript file and will add your translation to the js-translation.json file who's located in `pub/static/frontend/...`. In production mode you need to redeploy static content in order to see your new text translated.